# How can i call a function  that written in kernel module, from the user program?

Tags: c, module, operating-system, linux-kernel, kernel

sample driver created and loaded successfully, in that a user defined function is written, it does some actions. i need to write a user program that calls the user defined function in the driver module.

need help in following cases.

> 1. How can i get access to the driver code from a user program ?.
> 2. How can i call a function that written in kernel module, from the user program ?.

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make your driver to react on writes (or if necessary, ioctl) to a /dev/xxx file or a /proc/xxx file. Also, you can create a new syscall, but that's more of a toy as the module would only work on custom built kernels.

Edit: try http://www.faqs.org/docs/kernel/x571.html (on character device drivers.)

Comment: check this reference here.
https://github.com/sachinites/RIBDriver

It implements the user space to kernel communication using device files.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what your function does, but in general:

- If you want to **store** and **show** properties in the form of values (e.g. current brightness of a backlight), the standard way of doing would be using sysfs: http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt
- If you want to write/read values from a device (real or virtual), export memory or IO regions of a device to user space, or more generally control a device (e.g. setting resolution of a camera and capturing frames), you would use a character or block devices with the read/write/mmap and ioctl functions: http://luv.asn.au/overheads/chrdev-talk.html
- Finally if your function just controls something from the kernel, then sysfs or procfs should be the way to go. I am not sure why people are still using procfs nowadays, except for misc devices maybe.

So in general, you need to export your kernel functions to user space through **files**, by defining hooks that will be called when the file is opened, read, written (to copy data from/to user space), mmap'ed (to share memory areas without copying) or when an ioctl is invoked (to perform more general control).

Answer (score 1):

VDSO:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO

Kernel mode Linux:

http://www.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tosh/kml/

Answer (score 0):

for Qn.1:
   read/write/ioctl see file_operations
for Qn.2:
   1) system calls
   2) driver - ioctl